# Using a custom list of an Office 365 application in my .aspx

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

I have a custom list created in my Office 365 site, I want to display data in it in my .aspx page, and I tried the following :

```
     string url = "https://entreprise.sharepoint.com/sites/Develop/";
        SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
        {
            using (SPSite oSPsite = new SPSite(url))
            {
                oSPsite.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                using (SPWeb web = oSPsite.OpenWeb())
                {
                    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                    SPList list = web.Lists["users"];
                   if (list != null)
                   {
                        //gvHolidays.DataSource = list;
                        //gvHolidays.DataBind();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

But I get an error: `An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code`

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You should not be using the server object model with O365.  Try using an app or JSOM in a content/script editor web part.

Answer (score 0):

Reason for the error is that SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges is not supported in Sandboxed code so you need to revise your code to not use that.

Comment: if I eliminate that, I still get an error, another one

Comment: Perhaps also the Allowunsafeupdates needs to go? You don't need it for reading content.